# How to fill out grouped data by day?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

From events table, I get grouped events count by day and for this I use

```
SELECT event_date, COUNT(event_id) event_count FROM events
WHERE event_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-1, 'DD')
GROUP BY event_date
ORDER BY event_date
```

My problem here is that this returns only these days, where are some events

**2017-04-03 , 4

2017-04-05 , 2**

but I need get all consecutive days from Yesterday to next 30 day, and fill out this days from my grouped events data, like this

**2017-03-31 ,

2017-04-01 ,

2017-04-02 ,

2017-04-03 , 4

2017-04-04 ,

2017-04-05 , 2

2017-04-06 ,

... Next 30 days (with events count when events exists in my table)
...**

How to do that? Thank you for any help

Comment: Do you need next 30 days from yesterday or next 30 days from  last date which you have in table ?

Comment: next 30 days from yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can generate next 30 days from yesterday (see first subquery) and then simply `left join` it to your existing query.

Try this:

```
select  all_days.days  ,  certain_days.event_count from (
    select  TRUNC( sysdate + level - 2, 'DD') as days from DUAL connect by level <= 30
) all_days
left join (
    SELECT event_date, COUNT(event_id) event_count FROM events
    WHERE event_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-1, 'DD')
    GROUP BY event_date
) certain_days
on   all_days.days  =  certain_days.event_date
order by  all_days.days
```